# Pause timer from AppDelegate when applicationWillResignActive

Tags: ios, swift

I have a timer that I start/reset in my GameScene.swift file but when the application is minimised during a call or when the home button is pressed, it continues to run. How do I stop the timer and continue it when the app is active again?

```
if name == "player" {
        // first touch
        if playerFirstTouch {
            print("New Game")

            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "printDuration:", userInfo: NSDate(), repeats: true)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop this timer in **applicationDidEnterBackground** in app delegate or stop this timer in

**-(void)viewWillDisappear** in ViewController in which SKView is loaded ....